# How can I see what a shell script is doing?

Tags: command-line, scripts

In Windows, I can see the server running on the console. I can see if there is an error or what is loading and so on. But in Ubuntu server how can I see what the server is doing from the terminal?.

I am running a `.sh` file. I can see it running but I don't know what it is up to or if there is/was an error.

BTW I am using xampp.

[image]

Comment: there are many servers in linux.. which one are you running? logs are usually stored inside /var/log

Comment: I am using the easy ubuntu server and running l2jserver, I am going to give it a try to /var/log

Comment: I run for example                                                       
           gero@4790k:/opt/lampp$ sh -x ./startLoginServer.sh
           /////////////   sh: 0: Can't open ./startLoginServer.sh

Comment: There are many things to see. Please add to you question what it is that you want to see. What do you see in Microsoft's Windows.

Comment: I added a pic of what I see on windows

Comment: these in picture are actual foreground servers running.. maybe on linux that .sh script starts the servers in background see that sh script for a `&` sign at the end of each server start command; you have to start each server in its own terminal

Comment: what do you mean to see that sh script for a &?

Comment: the startLoginServer.sh is a .sh script file that runs the actual executable; if you put `&` after the executable call it will run it in background.. not much terminal logging

Comment: There was an answer here about the log files.  You need to find the log file associated with the application that is running, generally found in the `/var/log` folder.  Then in a terminal window type in `tail -f logfilename` as that should be showing you the output of the file as it grows.  I have seen that the logs might be in `/opt/lampp/logs`.

Comment: tried on every single log file inside /opt/lampp/logs without luck.

Comment: if you find the right `tail` or other command that has the info you want, you can watch it using `watch`.  This can provide refreshes at time intervals you specify (-n), highlighting the differences (-d) & more.

Answer (score 6):

The command you need is `tail -f`:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Since I see `lampp` mentioned here, the location might be in `/opt/lampp/logs/php_error_log` so:

```
tail -f /opt/lampp/logs/php_error_log
tail -f /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
tail -f /opt/lampp/logs/access_log
```